# domain name problem with django app dployed with heroku

Tags: python, django, web, heroku, adsense

i'm trying to add adsense to my django web app but i can't activate it because of "no content website" error.

i'm using heroku to publish my webapp and i've seen that my website work with this way "mywebsite.herokuapp.com" but doesn't work with "www.mywebapp.herokuapp.com" and it's probably because of that i had this error.

when i'm trying to acces to "www.mywebapp.herokuapp.com" my browser show me a page with that error : inaccessible website , DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE

in my settings.py file, the allowed_host line contains "mywebapp.herokuapp.com", "www.mywebapp.herokuapp.com"

did somebody can say to me how to fix that in heroku web app's settings eventually or directly in my project files.

thank you for helping me !

Comment: Your question says 'doesn't work with "www.mywebapp.herokuapp.com"' and then you refer to "www.mywebapp.com". Which domain are you referring to? Have you added your custom domain to your Heroku app and then configured its DNS as described in [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)?

Comment: yes excuse me that's make more sense now i think

Comment: for the solution i'm gonna try to setup a custom domain name to my app but if somebody has an other idea, it's welcome

Comment: no i was trying to add adsense with the domain name that heroku gave to me with de .herokuapp but like i said above i'm gonna try to put a custom domain and configure dns

Comment: I don't think Heroku routes `www.mywebapp.herokuapp.com` to `mywebapp.herokuapp.com`. Why can't you use the `mywebapp.herokuapp.com`? Or, yes, use a custom domain.